# Remove whitespaces in shell .SH file

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cygwin

Due to processes out of my control I need run multiple SH files which contains lengthy CURL commands. Problem is that whichever process created these commands seems to have included one line of whitespace at the very end. If I call it as is - it fails. If I physically open the file and hit backspace on the first full empty line and save the file - it works perfectly.

Any way to put some kind of command into the SH file so that it removes any unnecessary stuff?

Comment: Can you put some code to show what you've tried and what you expect ?

Comment: Can't post actual code, but its a long POST command that's made up of `curl 'https.............................' --compressed > /dev/clipboard` I expect it to be available in the clipboard which it is if I manually backspace the last line.

Answer (score 0):

More info would be helpful, but the following might work:
If you need to put something into each of the files that contain the curl commands as you mention, you could try putting exit as the last line of the curl script (also depends on how you're calling the 'curl files'

```
exit
```

If you can run a separate script against the files that have a blank line, perhaps sed the blank lines away?

```
sed -i s/^\s$// $fileWithLineOfSpaces
```

edit:
Or (after thinking about it), perhaps simply delete the last line of the file....

```
sed -i '$d' $file
```

Comment: That might work, forgive me but I'm new at this. What exactly should I type to delete the last line? Say, my file is cygwin64/bin/test.sh

Comment: Just replace "$file" in the last line of code with your file.  Example:
    sed -i '$d' cygwin64/bin/test.sh